# How does _.forEach work in lodash/fp as compared to lodash?

Tags: javascript, foreach, functional-programming, lodash

This snippet, which uses [lodash's `_.forEach`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#forEach),

```js
_.forEach({ 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }, function(value, key) {
  console.log(key + '=' + value);
})
```

prints

```
a=1
b=2
```

How does `_.forEach` work in `lodash/fp`?

If I try the snippet above, at the console it results in

```
ƒ (value, key) {
  console.log(key + '=' + value);
}
```

which is close to "I'm not using it the way I should".

If I try inverting the two inputs (as that's actually one main difference between `lodash` and `lodash/fp`),

```js
_.forEach(function(value, key) {
  console.log(key + '=' + value);
}, { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 })
```

I get

```
undefined=1
undefined=2
```

So my question is: is there a way to `_.forEach` on an object via `lodash/fp` and have access to both keys and values of the object?

Comment: Your second snippet should work (I've tried it and "works on my machine"). You can also use the curried version `_.forEach((value, key) => console.log(key + '=' + value))({a: 1, b: 2})`

Comment: This is truly strange... Anyway, hoping it can shed some light, I've just discovered that `_.VERSION` prints the version. On [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#VERSION) it prints `4.17.15`, whereas for me it prints `4.17.4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The parameters of the iteratee function are capped in Lodash FP](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide#capped-iteratee-arguments)

Quoting the documentation:

> #### Capped Iteratee Arguments
>
> Iteratee arguments are capped to avoid gotchas with variadic iteratees.
>
> ```
> // The `lodash/map` iteratee receives three arguments:
> // (value, index|key, collection)
> _.map(['6', '8', '10'], parseInt);
> // ➜ [6, NaN, 2]
>
> // The `lodash/fp/map` iteratee is capped at one argument:
> // (value)
> fp.map(parseInt)(['6', '8', '10']);
> // ➜ [6, 8, 10]
> ```

Different functions in Lodash FP will have the iteratee is capped to only 1 parameter - `_.forEach()` is among them. The only three that have the iteratee capped to two are `_.reduce()`, `_.reduceRight()`, and, `_.transform()`.

---

In order to iterate over both keys and values in Lodash FP, you can use `_.forEach()` over [`_.entries()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#toPairs). Since that gives the entries as key-value pairs, you can destructure them:

```js
const obj = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 };

_.forEach(function([value, key]) { // destructure the pair
  console.log(key + '=' + value);
}, _.entries(obj))                 // get as pairs
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)"></script>
```

A more readable way would be to compose them with [`_.flow()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#flow)

```js
const obj = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 };
const process = _.flow(
  _.entries,
  _.forEach(function([value, key]) {
    console.log(key + '=' + value);
  })
);
process(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)"></script>
```

Finally, you can avoid the destructuring, if you wish, by using [`_.spread()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#spread):

```js
const obj = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 };
const process = _.flow(
  _.entries,
  _.forEach(_.spread(function(value, key) {
    console.log(key + '=' + value);
  }))
);
process(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)"></script>
```